# Edit and write out pyparser results

Tags: python, parsing

A program I work with can import/export its internal hierarchical database **only** as a giant unstructured text file.  Sections set the meanings of lines which set the meanings of the following lines.

*pyparser* lets me define the syntax of this file, and create a Group() nested structure full of named attributes in each section.  But my goal is to be able to read the file, make some changes, and write it back out to re-import into the tool.

Is there a good way to modify ParseResults, or turn ParseResults into some sort of modifiable structure, that I can modify by named attribute access and write back out?  Or will I basically have to repeat my entire grammar definition in additional ad-hoc code to get back out the ordering I put in?

File format example below. This represents one physical part as defined in this section.  The second line, for example, says that there are 4 "pieces" below (OPEN/CLOSED) and then 2 "texts" after that (VALUE).

```
SOT\23           I 
37147500 38100000  4  3 1 0 2
OPEN   4   381000 0   1   
190500 762000
190500 1143000
2857500 1143000
2857500 -381000
OPEN   2   381000 0   1   
190500 -838200
190500 -1790700
OPEN   4   381000 0   1   
190500 -3429000
190500 -3810000
2857500 -3810000
2857500 -2286000
CLOSED 5   38100 0   20  
-2476500 2095500
5715000 2095500
5715000 -4762500
-2476500 -4762500
-2476500 2095500
VALUE     3810000     3810000   0.000  1     3810000      381000 N   LEFT   DOWN
Regular <Romansim Stroke Font>
Ref.Des.
VALUE     3810000     3810000   0.000  1     3810000      381000 N   LEFT     UP
Regular <Romansim Stroke Font>
Part Type
T0     0     0     0     1 
T0     -2667000 0     -2667000 2 
T3200400 -1333500 3200400 -1333500 3 
PAD 0 3
-2 1143000 RF  0.000 1905000 0   0   0  
-1 0   R  
0  0   R
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention `Group` and `ParseResults`, I assume you are using pyparsing. I usually search for the "pyparsing" tag for pyparsing questions.  You may want to try implementing your modifications in a parse action, and then using `transformString` to do the automated change.

You didn't describe what kind of changes you might want to make, so I imagined that the values for each `OPEN` and `CLOSED` were X-Y pairs, and you might want to convert by translating all the values by +10000.

To do this, start by writing a parser just for the `OPEN/CLOSED` sections. (We use `pyparsing_common.signed_integer` to parse the values, which will also do the str-to-int conversion.)

```
import pyparsing as pp
ppc = pp.pyparsing_common

open_closed_expr = (pp.oneOf("OPEN CLOSED") + pp.restOfLine 
                    + (ppc.signed_integer * 2)[...]("pairs"))
```

Then define a parse action to make this change:

```
# define a parse action to add 10000 to every integer pair value
def modify_integer_pairs(tokens):
    updated_pair_values = [x + 10000 for x in tokens.pairs]
    
    # create an updated string to return
    first_line = " ".join(tokens[:2])
    pairs_string = "\n".join("{} {}".format(*updated_pair_values[i:i+2])
                             for i in range(0, len(updated_pair_values), 2))
    return  = first_line + "\n" + pairs_string

open_closed_expr.addParseAction(modify_integer_pairs)
```

Try it out, using `transformString`:

```
updated_text = open_closed_expr.transformString(text)
print(updated_text)
```

Gives:

```
SOT\23           I 
37147500 38100000  4  3 1 0 2
OPEN    4   381000 0   1   
200500 772000
200500 1153000
2867500 1153000
2867500 -371000
OPEN    2   381000 0   1   
200500 -828200
200500 -1780700
OPEN    4   381000 0   1   
200500 -3419000
200500 -3800000
2867500 -3800000
2867500 -2276000
CLOSED  5   38100 0   20  
-2466500 2105500
5725000 2105500
5725000 -4752500
-2466500 -4752500
-2466500 2105500
VALUE     3810000     3810000   0.000  1     3810000      381000 N   LEFT   DOWN
Regular <Romansim Stroke Font>
Ref.Des.
VALUE     3810000     3810000   0.000  1     3810000      381000 N   LEFT     UP
Regular <Romansim Stroke Font>
Part Type
T0     0     0     0     1 
T0     -2667000 0     -2667000 2 
T3200400 -1333500 3200400 -1333500 3 
PAD 0 3
-2 1143000 RF  0.000 1905000 0   0   0  
-1 0   R  
0  0   R
```